# Reliable conditional copy and move constructors in template class with specializations

Tags: c++, c++17, copy-constructor, template-specialization, move-constructor

I discovered my `compressed_tuple<T1, T2>` class doesn't compile when either `T1` or `T2` don't have a copy and/or move constructor with the error **"attempting to reference a deleted function"**. That error refers to usage of a deleted copy constructor in the copy constructor of `compressed_tuple`. I understand what the error is, why I get it, and how to fix it. What I don't understand is how to do it without excessive specialization(elaborated on below).

`compressed_tuple` is my name for a pair that uses [EBO](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ebo) via specialization to minimize its size when at least one value is empty and derivable. i.e. `std::unique_ptr` is typically implemented with this mechanism to prevent empty deleters from affecting its size(otherwise plain `std::unique_ptr` would be larger than a pointer).

**TL:DR** Skip to the bottom, where I ask the actual question. Everything leading up to it is informational context.

Typically I would use specialization and call it a day, similar to this:

```
template<class T>
constexpr bool is_copyable_v = 
    std::is_copy_constructible_v<T> && std::is_copy_assignable_v<T>;
template<class T>
constexpr bool is_movable_v =
    std::is_move_constructible_v<T> && std::is_move_assignable_v<T>;

template<class T>
class example_base
{
public:
    T value;

protected:
    example_base() = default;
    example_base(const example_base&) = default;
    example_base(example_base&&) = default;
    ~example_base() = default;

    inline example_base& operator=(const example_base& source)
        noexcept(std::is_nothrow_copy_assignable_v<T>)
    {
        static_assert(is_copyable_v<T>, "T must be copyable.");

        if constexpr (is_copyable_v<T>) {
            value = source.value;
        }
        return *this;
    }
    inline example_base& operator=(example_base&& source)
        noexcept(std::is_nothrow_move_assignable_v<T>)
    {
        static_assert(is_movable_v<T>, "T must be movable.");

        if constexpr (is_movable_v<T>) {
            value = std::move(source.value);
        }
        return *this;
    }
};

// T is both copyable and movable.
template<
    class T,
    bool = is_copyable_v <T>,
    bool = is_movable_v<T>>
class example final : example_base<T>
{
    using base = example_base<T>;

public:
    example() = default;
    inline example(const example& source)
        noexcept(std::is_nothrow_copy_constructible_v<T>) :
        base(source) {}
    inline example(example&& source)
        noexcept(std::is_nothrow_move_constructible_v<T>) :
        base(std::move(source)) {}

    inline example& operator=(const example& source)
        noexcept(std::is_nothrow_copy_assignable_v<T>)
    {
        return static_cast<example&>(base::operator=(source));
    }
    inline example& operator=(example&& source)
        noexcept(std::is_nothrow_move_assignable_v<T>)
    {
        return static_cast<example&>(base::operator=(std::move(source)));
    }
};

// T is copyable, but not movable.
template<class T>
class example<T, true, false> final : public example_base<T>
{
    using base = example_base<T>;

public:
    example() = default;
    inline example(const example& source)
        noexcept(std::is_nothrow_copy_constructible_v<T>) :
        base(source) {}
    example(example&&) = delete;

    inline example& operator=(const example& source)
        noexcept(std::is_nothrow_copy_assignable_v<T>)
    {
        return static_cast<example&>(base::operator=(source));
    }
    example& operator=(example&&) = delete;
};

// T isn't copyable, but is movable.
template<class T>
class example<T, false, true> final : public example_base<T>
{
    using base = example_base<T>;

public:
    example() = default;
    inline example(example&& source)
        noexcept(std::is_nothrow_move_constructible_v<T>) :
        base(std::move(source)) {}
    example(const example&) = delete;

    inline example& operator=(example&& source)
        noexcept(std::is_nothrow_move_assignable_v<T>)
    {
        return static_cast<example&>(base::operator=(std::move(source)));
    }
    example& operator=(const example&) = delete;
};

// T is neither copyable nor movable.
template<class T>
class example<T, false, false> final : public example_base<T>
{
public:
    example() = default;
    example(const example&) = delete;
    example(example&&) = delete;

    example& operator=(const example&) = delete;
    example& operator=(example&&) = delete;
};
```

Which works fine but blows up exponentially if any other template parameters require further specialization.

`compressed_tuple` is quite large with all of its specializations, so I have omitted most of it:

```
// T1 is empty and inheritable, but T2 isn't, so derive from T1 and store T2.
// Handles both <..., true, true> and <..., true, false>.
template<class T1, class T2, 
    bool = std::is_empty_v<T1> && !std::is_final_v<T1>,
    bool = std::is_empty_v<T2> && !std::is_final_v<T2>>
class compressed_tuple final : private T1 
{
private:
    using base = T1;

    T2 second;

public:
    compressed_tuple(const compressed_tuple& source)
        noexcept(
            std::is_nothrow_copy_constructible_v<T1> &&
            std::is_nothrow_copy_constructible_v<T2>) :
        base(source),
        second(source.second) {}
    /*...*/
};

// T2 is empty and inheritable, but T1 isn't, so derive from T2 and store T1.
template<class T1, class T2>
class compressed_tuple<T1, T2, false, true> final : private T2 
{
private:
    using base = T2;

    T1 first;

public:
    compressed_tuple(const compressed_tuple& source)
        noexcept(
            std::is_nothrow_copy_constructible_v<T1> &&
            std::is_nothrow_copy_constructible_v<T2>) :
        base(source),
        first(source.first) {}
    /*...*/
};

// Neither T1 nor T2 are empty and derivable, so store both.
template<class T1, class T2>
class compressed_tuple<T1, T2, false, false> final
{
private:
    T1 first;
    T2 second;

public:
    compressed_tuple(const compressed_tuple& source)
        noexcept(
            std::is_nothrow_copy_constructible_v<T1> &&
            std::is_nothrow_copy_constructible_v<T2>) :
        first(source.first),
        second(source.second) {}
    /*...*/
};
```

What I'm trying to do could be achieved with the following:

```
template<
    class T,
    bool = is_copyable_v<T>,
    bool = is_movable_v<T>,
    bool = std::is_empty_v<T1> && !std::is_final_v<T1>,
    bool = std::is_empty_v<T2> && !std::is_final_v<T2>>
class compressed_tuple final { /*...*/ };

// ...specialize on all valid combinations...
```

Though it would require a large number of specializations. What I'm looking for is an alternative if possible.

To my understanding, SFINAE isn't an option for this. C++20 constraints would solve this very problem, but as of the time of this writing, it'll be quite some time before mainstream compilers are C++20 compliant. How can conditional copy and move constructors be implemented in C++17 without specializations or a large number of specializations?

Comment: Can you provide a concrete example (see [mcve]) of the error you're talking about? It's unclear to me what the specific problem is. Also "`T` is copyable, but not movable" isn't really a realistic case - that should never happen.

Comment: /OT: Your `bool = /*...*/` don't actually do anything. No SFINAE there.

Comment: @Barry I'm well aware that's what we prefer here on SO, however the problem is complex, though perhaps I can simplify it. This already is minimal, a complete and fully verifiable example would bloat this question and is in my opinion unnecessary to understand the problem. As unrealistic as that scenario is, it's still possible, and provided for coverage.

Comment: @Rakete1111 Some of the original conditions were named, and from what I've observed that part at least works as intended(providing something to specialize on i.e. EBO in the case of `compressed_tuple`.

Comment: @KobyDuck No it's not. There's no example demonstrating the problem. Which is why I don't understand what the problem is. It's not even clear to me _what_ doesn't compile, what the compile error is, etc.

Comment: `static_assert(is_copyable_v<T>);  if constexpr (is_copyable_v<T>)`. `if constexpr` seems redundant.

Comment: @Jarod42 The static assert results in a compiler error if you try to use it and the type isn't copyable. Checking if it's copyable is so it only tries to compile the copy if indeed the type is copyable. It's similar in purpose to SFINAE, but with an error message at the callsite.

Comment: `if constexpr` allows to reduce error message. Sad that it is needed :-/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two common approaches are:

- Default the special member functions, then arrange for them to become deleted (e.g., by using a special base class for this purpose).
- "Eric's trick":

  ```
  Foo& operator=(std::conditional_t<can_copy, Foo, nonesuch> const& rhs) {
      // implement
  }

  Foo& operator=(std::conditional_t<!can_copy, Foo, nonesuch> const&) = delete;
  ```

Comment: Defaulting the copy and move constructors(without arranging for them to be deleted) seems to work, though I haven't thoroughly tested it. Not sure why I didn't think to try that. In any case, thanks.

Comment: @Jarod42 It's named after Eric Fiselier, a libc++ maintainer. I do not know if there's something I can link to.

Comment: @KobyDuck You need to make special arrangements if you need to do something special (e.g., tuple's assignment operator needs to assign through reference). If the defaulted implementation is just fine then yes, you can just default them.